# Bash: Find folders with less than x files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

How would I go about finding all the folders in a directory than contain less than x number of `.flac` files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- For every subdirectory, print the subdirectory name if there are at most 42 `.flac` files in the subdirectory. To execute a command on the directories, replace `-print` by `-exec … \;`. POSIX compliant.

  ```
  find . -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*.flac; [ $# -le 42 ]' {} \; -print
  ```

  Note that this command won't work to search for directories containing zero `.flac` files (`"$0/*.flac"` expands to at least one word). Instead, use

  ```
  find . -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*.flac; ! [ -e "$1" ]' {} \; -print
  ```
- Same algorithm in zsh. `**/*` expands to all the files in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively. `**/*(/)` restricts the expansion to directories. `{.,**/*}(/)` adds the current directory. Finally, `(e:…:)` restricts the expansion to the matches for which the shell code returns 0.

  ```
  echo {.,**/*}(/e:'set -- $REPLY/*.flac(N); ((# <= 42))':)
  ```

  This can be broken down in two steps for legibility.

  ```
  few_flacs () { set -- $REPLY/*.flac(N); ((# <= 42)); }
  echo {.,**/*}(/+few_flacs)
  ```

<sub>**Changelog**:

​• handle x=0 correctly.</sub>

Comment: The first command prints *all* the subdirectories. `$#` is always at least 1 hence `[ $# -le 42 ]` is true when there are no `flac` files in the subdirectory.

Comment: @cYrus: If there are no flac files, there are fewer than 42 flac files. Ok, I should have mentioned that my solutions only work for 42 > 0, so they won't work to search for directories containing no flac files (you need a different, simpler command).

Comment: I'm not talking about searching directories without `flac` files (x=0). I was saying that if a directory contains no `flac` files `$#` is 1 because `$1` is literally `path-to-dir/*.flac` (as there's no expansion) the directory is printed anyway. It's just a different point of view, I'm assuming that a directory without `flac` files doesn't match the request.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$MAX` with your own limit:

```
find -name '*.flac' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | while read -r n d ; do [ $n -lt $MAX ] && printf '%s\n' "$d" ; done
```

**Note:** This will print all the subdirectories with a number of `.flac` files between `0` and `$MAX` (both excluded).

Comment: Make that `read -r n d` in case directory names contain backslashes, and `printf "%s "$d"` in case directory names contain whitespace or `-\['"\\\``.

Comment: Thanks for the `-r`, I really missed that! But I can't see any problem with echo, it correctly works with directories like: st r\a \\`n-[g\"e

Comment: sorry, wrong set of special characters. I should have said `-*?\\[`. Try creating two directories called `foo` and `f*`, with `f*` matching. Or a directory called `foo  bar` (two spaces). Or (depending on your shell) a directory called `-e` or `-n`.

Comment: A directory called `-e`... evil!

Comment: To avoid any issues with glob substitutions you should use `-name '*.flac'`.